# NVDA not reading text inside div tag.(After getting focus through tabIndex=0)

Tags: jquery, focus, accessibility, nvda

I am having trouble with nvda. I have one main div tag and and inside that div tag there are multiple div tags. Whenever I will click on button this main div tag get focused. I am expecting that screen reader should read the entire content. Can I know what pieces of code I am missing.

This is muy fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o27ogt2z/

HTML Code:

```
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
<div id="mrndialog" class="mrndialog" style="display: block;">
<div id="mrn_description" tabindex="0" aria-label="MRN detail description">
<label for="MRN title">
<div><span id="label_mrn_title">
 <h3>Where is the Health/Medical Record number?</h3>
</span></div></label>
<label for="MRN Description">

<div id="label_mrn_body_1">You'll find this number on a Kaiser Permanente 
card.It's the number used when making appointments.</div>
<div id="label_mrn_body_2">If you are in Northern California, don't include 
the '11' prefix when entering the MRN.</div></label></div>
<div><button class="button i18n" id="back_mrn_button" role="button">       
<b>BACK</b></button></div></div>
```

This is my JS file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnSave").click(
        function () {
            $("#mrn_description").focus()
            AlertSave();
        }            
    );
  $("#back_mrn_button").click(
        function () {
            AlertSave();
        }            
    );
});

function AlertSave() {
alert("Alert Message OnClick");
}
```

Expected is: 1: I will click on save button click. So focus will will get transferred to "mrn_description" div. After that I am expecting screen reader to read everything inside that div. Including child div and span. while getting focused **NVDA** is not reading anything. After I tab focus will go to the back button. Now if I will so shift + tab (getting back) to get focus on "mrn_description" tag then it **NVDA** reading everything. Any help with fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation reads for me in NVDA with Firefox, although not in the most ideal way. I would recommend some changes.

1. One of the reasons you may be running into difficulties is because you are causing the alert window to pop up then you want the focused text to be read. Remove the call to the alert window and it should read how you expect.
2. Do not wrap the contents in `<label>`. `<label>` should only be used with form input elements. In your implementation you don't really need the `<label>` element.
3. The `for` attributes on the `<label>` are invalid. They cannot contain spaces.
4. You don't need `role="button"` on the `<button>` element. That is redundant.
5. Don't put `aria-label` attributes on a text element. In general, they will not be read by screen readers.